# Priority execution of methods i iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm developing an application that should login to a remote service in the first view controller I create a UI to insert username and password.
When I press on the button login I make the following check:

- I check if the field aren't empty with a simple if
- From my button starts a segue to the internal view controller, before it shows me the internal view controller I added a method that should check if the user can login or not. In this method I call an external class in which I do the connection to the server to authenticate the user

The method to call the external class is the follow:

```
- (BOOL)loginSuccessWith:(NSString*)userName and:(NSString*)password {
    ConnectionHandler *connectionHandler = [[ConnectionHandler alloc]init];
    if ([connectionHandler startConnectionToServer:@"serverAddress" andUsername:userName withPassword:password andInstallationId:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"instId"]]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

As you can see if the method return YES or NO if the user can be logged or not.
In the `ConnectionHandler` class I wrote the following code:

```
#import "ConnectionHandler.h"

@interface ConnectionHandler() {
    BOOL authenticated;
}
@end

@implementation ConnectionHandler

- (BOOL)startConnectionToServer:(NSString *)address andUsername:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password andInstallationId:(NSString*) installationId {
    if (![self sendRequestToURL:address withMethod:@"POST" withUsername:username withPassword:password andInstallationId: installationId]) {
        NSLog(@"Impossibile connettersi");
        return NO;
    } else {
        if (authenticated) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }
}

- (id)sendRequestToURL:(NSString *)url withMethod:(NSString *)method withUsername:(NSString*)username withPassword:(NSString*)password andInstallationId:(NSString*)installationId {
    NSURL *finalURL = [[NSURL alloc]init];

    if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {
        finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Metodo no previsto");
    }

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&installationId=%@", username, password, installationId];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)postData.length];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:finalURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        [connection start];
    }
    return connection;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // Parsing della risposta dal server parlare con Giancarlo per vedere che tipo di risposta ottengo
    NSDictionary *json;
    NSError *err;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];
    if (err) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AT Brain" message:@"Impossibile satbilire una connessione con il server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        NSString *error_code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"error_code"]];
        int success = [[json objectForKey:@"success"] intValue];
        NSString *error_desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"error_desc"]];

        if ([self autenthicationOkWithErrorCode:error_code withSuccess:success andErrorDesc:error_desc]) {
            authenticated = YES;
        } else {
            authenticated = NO;
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)autenthicationOkWithErrorCode:(NSString*)error_code withSuccess:(int)success andErrorDesc:(NSString*)error_desc {

    int errCode = [error_code intValue];

    if (success == 1) {
        return YES;
    } else if (success == 0) {
        if (errCode == 2) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AT Brain" message:@"Controlla di aver inserito username, password e di avere un installationId" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
            return NO;
        }
        if (errCode == 3) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AT Brain" message:@"Credenziali non valide, inserisci username e password corrette" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
            return NO;
        }
        if (errCode == 4) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AT Brain" message:@"Utente non autorizzato ad accedere al servizio" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
            return NO;
        }
        if (errCode == 5) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AT Brain" message:@"L'utenza a cui stai cercando di accedere è già associata ad un utente diverso" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
            return NO;
        }
        if (errCode == 6) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AT Brain" message:@"Installation ID errato" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I can connect to the server without problem, but before the `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` is called it execute all the code in the `- (BOOL)startConnectionToServer:(NSString *)address andUsername:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password andInstallationId:(NSString*) installationId` and it returns NO so the segue in the login view controller doesn't work because the method `-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` returns NO.
So my problem is how to wait the execution of the method `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` is done before execute the else section in method `- (BOOL)startConnectionToServer:(NSString *)address andUsername:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password andInstallationId:(NSString*) installationId`?
I hope you understand my issue and I hope you will help me to fix it, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` is asynchronous. You kick it off and it immediately returns. You get callbacks (such as `connectionDidFinishLoading`) when it completes. That's the point at which you can check for success and move onto the next step.

I assume that `loginSuccessWith:and:` is called on the main thread (this is a very strange name for a method; you probably meant `loginWithUsername:password:`). So it can't block waiting for a network request that may take a very long time to complete. You'd hang the entire UI.

The [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA) has a great deal of information on how to design this. Look first at `NSURLSession`, and if it doesn't meet your needs, then use the lower-level `NSURLConnection`. With `NSURLSession`, you can pass completion blocks that will run whenever the operation completes.

Comment: Don't forget to also handle `connection:didFailWithError:` in case of failure.